# Issue when moving from Apache to Lighttpd

Tags: apache-2.2, lighttpd, joomla, pear

This might not be the right place, but we think its narrowed down to a Lighttpd config issue on our end, just cannot pinpoint.  Asked in Virtuemart and Lighttpd forums with no luck.

We have a live site on Apache and wanted to go over to Lighttpd like the rest of our 30+ servers. This is the last one, but we have been battling this issue now for some time.

The problem is with this website, it runs Virtuemart, and under Lighttpd, the vmLogger Messages are no longer appearing. (http://virtuemart.net/documentation/Developer_Manual/vmLogger.html)

When a person is checking out in Virtuemart, and does not select a Shipping Address, the Apache server gives us the vmLogger message, on Lighttpd nothing! It is driving us crazy. We have dumped variables, checked configurations, PEAR install, etc.

Anyone have any idea why this might break on Lighttpd? Just to make sure we were sane, we setup another Dev environment with Apache 2.2, PHP 5.2.17 and MySQL and it ran fine out of the box, showing the errors.

We thought it could be PEAR, PEAR include path, Fast-cgi setup, not sure...

Some other variables that might help:

Apache successful install is on CentOS with cPanel

Lighttpd unsuccessful install is on Ubuntu and from command line. Could we be missing some library, reference to PEAR, etc? All our other servers are on Ubuntu/Lighttpd and work great.

Answer (score 0):

Does each feature from your apache conf have the equivalent configured in lighttpd?

Are there any .htaccess files hidden deep inside the site that you may have overlooked?

A good test might be to setup a barebones php file with some `$vmLogger` logging calls and see if you can get that working. Before trying to get the whole site up.